# jQuery Collapse accordion block default open/expand for specific Collapse block only with a specific id 'myID11'

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have this script for an accordion/collapse block. It has just one `<div>` which can open/close. By default it is closed/collapsed now. The accordion appears only on mobile. How do I manage the default state is expanded?

```
/**
   * Create a simple mobile accordion.
   */
  Drupal.cgl.mobaccordion = function() {
    var mobaccordion = $('.mobaccordion');

    mobaccordion.each(function() {
      var mobaccordionTitle = $(this).find('.mobaccordion-title');
      var mobaccordionBody = $(this).find('.mobaccordion-body');
      var mobaccordionIcon = $(this).find('.mobaccordion-icon');
      var mobaccordionId = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
      var target = window.location.pathname + '#' + mobaccordionId;

      if ( (Drupal.cgl.isMobile()) && (mobaccordionIcon.length == 0) && (mobaccordionTitle.length != 0 ) ){
        // Don't close accordion when referred to title.
        if(window.location.hash !=  mobaccordionId) {
          mobaccordionBody.hide();
        }
          // Create icon to click.
          $(this).prepend('<a href="' + target + '" class="mobaccordion-icon" title="Dit menu-onderdeel kunt u uitklappen"><span class="element-invisible">Ingeklapt, klik om uit te klappen</span></a>');
          var mobaccordionIcon = $(this).find('.mobaccordion-icon');

          // Events when title or icons are clicked or pressed.
          $(mobaccordionIcon).add(mobaccordionTitle).on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var parent = $(this).parents('.mobaccordion');
            Drupal.cgl.mobaccordionToggle(parent);
          });

        //$('#mobaccordion-11').addClass('open');      

      }
      else if (Drupal.cgl.isMobile() == false) {
        //unset and remove everything when screen is not mobile.
        $(this).find('.mobaccordion-body').show();
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        $(mobaccordionIcon).add(mobaccordionTitle).off('click');
        $('.mobaccordion-icon').remove();
      }
    });
  };

  Drupal.cgl.mobaccordionToggle = function(mobaccordion) {
    mobaccordion.find('.mobaccordion-body').slideToggle();
    mobaccordion.toggleClass('open');
    mobaccordion.find('.mobaccordion-icon').toggleClass('active');
    mobaccordion.find('.mobaccordion-icon .element-invisible').remove();
    if (mobaccordion.hasClass('open')){
      mobaccordion.find('.mobaccordion-icon').append('<span class="element-invisible">Uitgeklapt, klik om in te klappen</span>');
    }else{
      mobaccordion.find('.mobaccordion-icon').append('<span class="element-invisible">Ingeklapt, klik om uit te klappen</span>');
    }
  };
```